# Exposing A Containerized Web App on a Public Domain

Tags: docker, dns

I am trying to expose my containerized web app to the Internet over a public domain, but all the articles out there seem to be teaching how to play around with Docker's local network, for example [how to run a containerized DNS server](http://www.damagehead.com/blog/2015/04/28/deploying-a-dns-server-using-docker/) or [running a DNS server in Docker](https://medium.com/@thiago.nobayashi/running-a-dns-server-in-docker-61cc2003e899). Even if I set up a DNS server that resolves an IP e.g. 172.20.0.3 to a domain like exmaple.com, then DNS service will translate example.com to 172.20.0.3 which is obviously only local to the docker network and not accessible from the outside.

The scenario seems easy. I have a docker host with a public static IP lets say `64.233.191.255`, and I have multiple domains on it. Each domain is mapped to a web server and will serve a (containerized) web application. Each application has its own network defined in docker-compose.yml under the `networks` section on which all other services related to the web app e.g. mariadb, redis, etc. communicate. Should I have a DNS server inside every container I create? How do I translate local addresses to the static public IP address so as to make the web apps available on their respective domains on port 80?
I found a service called ngrok that exposes a container over a public domain name like xxxx.ngrok.io, but that is not what I want. I would like to serve my website on my own domain.

[image]

This has proved to be everything but trivial to me. Also, there's no explicit tutorial on Docker's documentation on how to do this. I suppose this is not how it is supposed to be done in real world as they probably do it via Kubernetes or OpenShift.
Should I have a bind9 configuration on the host or a containerized bind9 to manage DNS queries? Do I need iptables rules for this scenario?

Comment: It seems like you need a proxy, e.x nginx to attend HTTP/HTTPS queries on port 80/443 and route the traffic to each apache container (considering the incoming domain). 
In other hand, you could use a cloud DNS, but if you prefer have your own so you need to delegate each zone domain to your server and configure there each zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map both domains to the public ip via DNS and than use an reverse proxy to forward the requests to the correct apache server.

So basically 3 vhosts inside the docker host.

Vhost 1 (the reverse proxy) gets the request maps the domain to Vhost 2 or Vhost 3 address.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: I don't understand why we should have 3 virtual hosts. Are they all on the host? Or are the two inside docker containers? Would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: All are inside the docker host below the public IP. You need some tool to connect domain to the desired host. And since you only want use one IP with the same port for both applications and only one server can run on specific ip port combination you need to have a dispatcher on this ip port combination.

Answer (score 1):

you can use reverse proxy with Nginx for each application. For example, you're running two apps on port 3000 and 3001. Assign a proper DNS for each application.

like localhost:3000 maps to example1.com